# Replace text in a file between two strings from another text file using python

Tags: python, string, text, replace

I have file which has alot of data with some lines as

```
*PART, NAME=Part-Default
**
*NODE, NSET=ALLNODES
1,  -175.443970,    -165.165787
2,  -175.143875,    -161.285782
3,  -171.282181,    -163.266525
...
...
...
**
*ELEMENT, TYPE=CPE4R, ELSET=EB2
       1,       3,       2,       1,       4
       2,       6,       5,       2,       3
```

I want to replace the text between

*NODE, NSET=ALLNODES and the first occurance of ** after that from another file which has the data of the form i.e. only numbers separated with comma!

```
1,  -75.443970, -15.165787
2,  -75.143875, -11.285782
3,  -71.282181, -13.266525
```

I am able to read all the lines of another file with the simple command

```
file=open(fileName,'r')
for lines in file:
```

but could not figure out the replacement method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want to replace those data with others from another file?

Comment: @IronFist, exactly. Is it not clear from the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the contents of your file into a string.

```
with open('your_file', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Get the text between the two occurrences.

```
starting_text = 'whatever your first bound is'
ending_text = 'whatever your second bound is'
to_replace = contents[contents.find(starting_text)+len(starting_text):contents.rfind(ending_text)]
```

Then replace it.

```
contents = contents.replace(to_replace, 'whatever you want to replace it with')
```

And then you can rewrite it back into a file.

You could use the same approach to find the text that you're going to replace it with if it's in another file.

(This isn't compiled by the way, so it may not be entirely correct)

Answer (score 0):

```
    # if your input file is large, process it line by line:
   infh=open('NameOfFileWithLotsOfData','r')
   outfh=open('NameOfOutputFile','w')

   flag_replacing=False


   while True:
        line = infh.readline()
        if not flag_replacing:
            # only write out the line if not reading between *NODE and ** lines
            outfh.write(line)
        if line.startswith('*NODE'):
            flag_replacing=True
        if line.startswith('**'):
            if flag_replacing:
                # this is the time to insert the other file
                insertfh=open('FileToInsert','r')
                outfh.write(insertfh.read())
                flag_replacing=False
```

Comment: since the file has multiple ** occurrences the script fails. The text should only be replaced until the first occurrence of the **

Comment: Your question was not specific enough... the replacing only happens when the script sees the *NODE. If you want to only replace when *NODE is seen the first time, then break out at the end of the script and copy the rest of the file...